# What is real world example for priority queue?

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, queue, priority-queue, lock-free

I'm writing a Lock-Free C library, and I'm going to implement a priority queue. However, the goal of my library is not completeness of the data structures, I just want to implement some typical ones and then write a mirco-benchmark to show that the lock-free ones perform better under some special cases than the lock-based ones. So I want to know if there're some typical applications that the priority queue plays an important roles. (open-source projects are the best.) Then I can use them as a benchmark.

Comment: Check : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-priority-queue/

Comment: @PriyaJain Thank you very much, your infomation is helpful to me!

Comment: Glad that it helped. Attached more info in answer sections. Hope that it helps.

Comment: [Discrete event simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation#Events_list).

Comment: @LiuShenming Just for your info, you are supposed to accept and upvote correct answer and upvote other helpful answer. This expects community from everyone. Read this meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few to be listed:
`1. Dijkstra’s Shortest Path Algorithm
2. Prim’s algorithm
3. Huffman codes for Data compression.
4. Heap sort
5. Load balancing on servers.`

There are various applocation being pointed out in :
https://www.cdn.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-priority-queue/

Also, the wiki itself has an extensive list of application and parameters against which you can benchmark your comparision(refer section Summary of running times):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: Instead mentioning link, you should get the content here and write it in your own word. Imagine, `geeksforgeeks` is down for some reason, then your answer would be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

[Priority queues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) are different from queues in the sense that they ***do not act on the FIFO*** principle.

> ...The ***elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their
>   natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided*** at queue construction
>   time...

One of the real world example would be [Priority Scheduling](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/5_CPU_Scheduling.html) algorithm where *each job is assigned a priority and the job with the highest priority gets scheduled first*

Answer (score 1):

The most common uses for priority queues that I see in real life are:

1) Prioritized work queues:  when a thread is ready for more work, it picks the highest priority available task from a priority queue.  This is a great application for lock-free queues.

2) Finding the closest restaurants/hotels/bathrooms/whatever to a given location.  The algorithm to retrieve these from pretty much any spacial data structure uses a priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a product, you breakdown things into smaller chunks (stories). Then assign a priority for each. Then pick it up, work on it and close.

JIRA stories are relatable example for Priority Queues.